# Choosing authentication-provider jdbc-user-service vs user-service-ref

Tags: spring, spring-security

i want to implement spring security login and remember me
and i am confused between using **jdbc-user-service** or **user-service-ref**
as my authentication-provider
can anyone please describe to me what is the difference between both, when to go for one or the other, coz what i can see is that both are used to lookup user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<jdbc-user-service>` configures a built-in [`JdbcDaoImpl`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) as a source of user details. It loads user detials from predefined database tables using JDBC.

If you need to customize user lookup, you can create a custom [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) instead and reference it with `user-service-ref`. It can be useful in the following cases:

- You need a more complex user lookup logic
- You want to reuse existing services instead of doing raw JDBC lookups
- You want to add extra information to `UserDetails` objects returned by `UserDetailsService`
- Etc

Comment: so you suggest to use user-service-ref, if so can you please give me a link to a good example, thanks.

Comment: @Jsword: I don't think you should use `user-service-ref` if `<jdbc-user-service>` is enough for your task.

Comment: i got you, can you please suggest me a link about the advantages of user-service-ref.

Comment: and what about the remember me, is it require a UserDetails or can it work without it ?

Comment: @Jsword: As long as you have only one `UserDetailsService` it your context, Remember Me uses it automatically. Otherwise you need to use `<remember-me>`'s `user-service-ref` attribute.

Comment: so if i am using the JDBC lookup and i want to implement remember me, i will have to use UserDetailsService ?